# How to install Google Chrome version 88 for ubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, google-chrome, google

I am having google chrome version 90.0.4430.93 (the latest one). Due to some dependency, I want to install version 88. So, are there any leads or any kind of suggestion on how to install it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible. Open terminal and type:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_88.0.4324.96-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./google-chrome-stable_88.0.4324.96-1_amd64.deb
```

Note: if you want to pib/hold this version - use single long command below:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-meld
Package: google-chrome-stable
Pin: version 88.0.4324.96-1
Pin-Priority: 1337
EOF
```

to keep the 88 version installed.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, it worked.

Comment: At this point the link gives a 404 unfortunately.

Comment: Here it is an updated url of version 88: https://mirror.cs.uchicago.edu/google-chrome/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_88.0.4324.96-1_amd64.deb, all the other versions can be found here: https://mirror.cs.uchicago.edu/google-chrome/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/

Answer (score 3):

There has been a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408325/download-older-versions-of-google-chrome-for-linux) and has several answers, but many of them seem outdated.

[This site](https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php) mentioned in one of the answers still works, but it doesn't happen to have version 88, only 86 and then 90.

However, [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=inurl%3A%2Fdeb%2Fpool%2Fmain%2Fg%2Fgoogle-chrome-stable%2F) (also mentioned in one of the answers) can find mirrors of Google Chrome repository that hopefully still have old versions. Using this search, I found that version 88 is available [here](http://170.210.201.179/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/). However, it's not clear what a site is this, so better verify your download.

If you don't necessary need actual Chrome (with all Google add-ons), you can apparently download any version of Chromium from their build archive, but it seems that [the process of finding a particular version](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium) is not very straightforward and it requires you to know an exact version number (like "88.x.y.z"). I did a search on this archive for you and seems that Chromium version 88 can be found [here](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Linux_x64/827102/) - however, I don't know which of the various files present there are actually needed, is this only "chrome-linux.zip" or something more...

I also found that [official Debian repository for Chromium](https://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/c/chromium/) still has version 88. (I'm using Debian repo, as in Ubuntu Chromium is now installed via snap, which means older versions are not available).